Nav Bar Not Showing
Navbar.js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './navbar.scss';
import Logo from '../../image/Logo.png';
import Admin from '../../image/eye.png';

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className='navBar'>
      <div style={{width: "90%", display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
        <Link to="/">
        <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" className='Logo'/>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/admin">
        <img src={Admin} alt="Admin" className='Admin'/>
        </Link>
          
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


navbar.scss
.navBar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
  }
  
  .Logo, .Admin {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 3vh;
    width: 5%;
  }

index.js where the route are there
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import{BrowserRouter,Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './pages/Home/home.js';
import Err404 from './pages/Error/err404.js';
import CRUD from './pages/CRUD/crud.js'
import Navbar from './pages/Navbar/navbar.js';
import Footer from './pages/Footer/footer.js'
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Navbar/>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}></Route>
    <Route path='/CRUD' element={<CRUD/>}></Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<Err404/>}></Route>
  </Routes>
  <Footer/>
  </BrowserRouter>
);


in this following I just put img and no Link the image are showing but as i do this it is not showing can anyone help me with this?
 not showing
without  showing
I tried working with scss but I did not find any problem there

There are several problems with your code, some of which are stylistic.
Issue 1: Missing Route for /admin
One main problem is that you have a link to /admin, but you don't have a route for /admin. Instead, you only have routes for / and /*, with the * route being used for paths that don't match and show an error page. Therefore, when you navigate to the admin page, the Link component works as intended, but it renders the error page, which I assume you don't want.
Issue 2: Using the Outlet Component
A feature that react-router-dom provides is the Outlet component. Instead of putting everything in one file as you do now, you can use the Outlet component to render the dynamic parts of your application. For more information on Outlet, visit React Router Outlet. You didn't specify which version of React Router you're using, but I'll assume it's a newer version where Outlet is available.
With that in mind, I recommend setting up your application like this:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home, Admin } from './pages';
import { Layout } from './Layout';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="admin" element={<Admin />} /> {/* Add the Admin route */}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Outlet /> {/* This will render the matched child route */}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

Issue 3: CSS/SCSS for the Navbar
There is a problem with the position: static style. This will place the navbar content relative to the viewport instead of the top of the page. If you want it to stick to the top of the page as you scroll, then use position: sticky. Otherwise, if you just need it to stay at the top of the page and exit the viewport as one scrolls down (like most web apps), you can delete the position style entirely.
.navBar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  /* Remove position: static if it's not needed */
}

By making these adjustments, your application should work as intended and be more maintainable.

